# AWS S3 upload file name mismatch

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am able to upload multiple files to s3 bucket at once. However there is a mismatch in the file name the one I provided and uploaded file. I am interested in file name as I need to generate cloud front signed url based on that.

**File generation code**

```
final String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + pictureData.getFileName();
final File file = new File(fileName); //fileName is -> 1594125913522_image1.png
writeByteArrayToFile(img, file);
```

**AWS file upload code**

```
public void uploadMultipleFiles(final List<File> files) {

        final TransferManager transferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(amazonS3).build();
        try {
            final MultipleFileUpload xfer = transferManager.uploadFileList(bucketName, null, new File("."), files);
            xfer.waitForCompletion();
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.info("InterruptedException occurred=>" + exception);
            }
        } catch (AmazonServiceException exception) {
            if (LOGGER.isInfoEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.info("AmazonServiceException occurred =>" + exception);
            }
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

Uploaded file name is **94125913522_image1.png**. As you can see first two characters disappeared. What am I missing here. I am not able to figure out. Kindly advice.

```
private static void writeByteArrayToFile(final byte[] byteArray, final File file) {
        try (OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(file.getName())))) {
            outputStream.write(byteArray);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new FileIllegalStateException("Error while writing image to file", exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there something happening with the files before you get to `uploadMultipleFiles`? also, is `writeByteArrayToFile` supposed to have file as the first argument?

Comment: I have updated the question with that method. Through debug I have seen that during aws upload itself some how file name is getting changed.

Comment: On analysis, I found this issue is occurring in  TransferManager. If I switch to aws sdk putObject method then it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

### The reason of the problem

You lose the first two charecters of the file names because of the third argument of this method:

```
transferManager.uploadFileList(bucketName, null, new File("."), files);
```

### What happens in this case

So, what is the third argument:

```
/**
...
* @param directory
* The common parent directory of files to upload. The keys
* of the files in the list of files are constructed relative to
* this directory and the virtualDirectoryKeyPrefix.
...
*/
public MultipleFileUpload uploadFileList(... , File directory, ...){...}
```

And how will it be used:

```
...
int startingPosition = directory.getAbsolutePath().length();
            if (!(directory.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(File.separator)))
                startingPosition++;
...
String key = f.getAbsolutePath().substring(startingPosition)...
```

Thus, the directory variable is used to define a starting index to trim file paths to get file keys.

When you pass **new File(".")** as a directory, the parent directory for your files will be **{your_path}.**

But this is a directory, and you need to work with files inside it. So the common part, retrieved from your directory file, is **{your_path}./**

That is 2 symbols more than you actually need. And for this reason this method trims the 2 extra characters - an extra shift of two characters when trimming the file path.

### The solution

If you only need to work with the current directory, you can pass the current directory as follows:

```
MultipleFileUpload upload = transferManager.uploadFileList(bucketName, "", 
                            System.getProperty("user.dir"), files);
```

But if you start working with external sources, it won't work. So you can use this code, which creates one MultipleFileUpload per group of files from one directory.

```
private final String PATH_SEPARATOR = File.separator;
private String bucketName;
private TransferManager transferManager;

public void uploadMultipleFiles(String prefix, List<File> filesToUpload){
    Map<File, List<File>> multipleUploadArguments = 
                  getMultipleUploadArguments(filesToUpload);
    for (Map.Entry<File, List<File>> multipleUploadArgument:
                                      multipleUploadArguments.entrySet()){
        try{
            MultipleFileUpload upload = transferManager.uploadFileList(
                    bucketName, prefix,
                    multipleUploadArgument.getKey(),
                    multipleUploadArgument.getValue()
            );
            upload.waitForCompletion();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}

private Map<File, List<File>> getMultipleUploadArguments(List<File> filesToUpload){
    return filesToUpload.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(this::getDirectoryPathForFile));
}

private File getDirectoryPathForFile(File file){
    String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    String directoryPath = filePath.substring(0, filePath.lastIndexOf(PATH_SEPARATOR));
    return new File(directoryPath);
}
```